# Are there any security risks with exposing a user's unique MongoDB _id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security

In my web app I store users'data in MongoDB documents. These have unique `_id` properties. To retrieve uploads associated with an item that a user has created I have created the following API:

```
/api/uploads/:user_id/:item_id/:fileName
```

On the backend I then simply return the file at location `/uploads/<user_id>/<item_id>/<fileName>`

Although item records themselves will have unique IDs, this folder structure will make it cleaner to delete all items associated with one user, as I can simply delete the entire folder named `<user_id>`.

However in setting things up this way I am clearly exposing the user's unique _id to all people accessing their public uploads.

Now my question is, is there any way in which this could pose a security risk? What could a malicious hacker do with a user's unique id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's a significant risk.  In concept, any information you provide can be used by hackers to malicious intent. There's nothing particularly special about the _id that makes it more of a risk than anything else you might put out there.

Regardless of what you put in the URL, you'll want to make sure you're enforcing proper access control and ensuring availability, etc.

Comment: One thing to note with `ObjectId`'s is that they contain [information](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) (they aren't random nor simply sequential), although this is generally not a problem.